# Convergence of a sequence of projections

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convex-optimization

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact, convex set, and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix ($P \succ 0$).

Consider the projection $\Pi_P: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow C$ defined as 
$$ \Pi_P(v) := \arg\min_{x \in C} \left\| x-v \right\|_P $$
for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am wondering if, for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it holds that
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \,\Pi_{P+ \epsilon I}\left( -\left( P+ \epsilon I \right)^{-1} v \right) = \Pi_P( -P^{-1} v) $$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Comments. It can be shown that $ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \,\Pi_{P}\left( -\left( P+ \epsilon I \right)^{-1} v \right) = \Pi_P( -P^{-1} v) $. I have shown the claim for the simpler case $P = p I$, $p>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I use $-v$ instead of $v$ in my answer to save some minus signs.)

The unique projections are characterized by the variational inequalities
\begin{align*}
 \big\langle
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 c
 ,
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 \big\rangle_{P + \varepsilon \, I}
 &\le
 0
 \qquad\forall c \in C
 ,\\
 \big\langle
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 -
 c
 ,
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 -
 P^{-1} v
 \big\rangle_P
 &\le
 0
 \qquad\forall c \in C
 .
\end{align*}
Now, we use $c = \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v$ in the first inequality
and
$c = \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v$
in the second one.

Adding the resulting inequalities and switching to the Euclidean scalar product yields
\begin{equation*}
 \big\langle
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 ,
 (P + \varepsilon \, I) \, \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 P \, \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 \big\rangle
 \le
 0
 .
\end{equation*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
 &\big\lVert
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 \big\rVert_P^2
 \\
 &\qquad+
 \varepsilon \, \big\langle
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 ,
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 \big\rangle
 \le
 0
 .
\end{align*}
follows.
Since the projections belong to $C$ and since $C$ is bounded, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
 \big\lVert
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 -
 \Pi_{P} P^{-1} v
 \big\rVert_P
 \le
 \varepsilon \,
 \big\lVert
 \Pi_{P + \varepsilon \, I} (P + \varepsilon \, I)^{-1} v
 \big\rVert_{P^{-1}}
 \le
 \varepsilon \, L
 ,
\end{equation*}
where $L$ depends on the diameter of $C$ and on the eigenvalues of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

I asssume when you write $\|\cdot\|_P$, you're talking about the norm corresponding to the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle_P = x^T P y$.
Thus $\Pi_R(-R^{-1} v)$ is the $x \in C$ that minimizes
$$F_R(x) = \|x + R^{-1} v\|_R^2 - v^T R^{-1} v = x^T R x + 2 x^T v $$

Since $F_P(x)$ is strictly convex, it has a unique minimum on the compact convex set $C$, let's say at $x_0$.  For any $\delta > 0$ there is $\eta > 0$
such that $F_P(x) > F_P(x_0) + \eta$ for $\|x - x_0\| > \delta$.  As $\epsilon \to 0+$, $F_{P+\epsilon I} \to F_P$ uniformly on $C$, so for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ we will have $F_{P+\epsilon I}(x) > F_{P}(x_0) + \eta/2$ for $\|x - x_0\| > \delta$ while $F_{P+\epsilon I}(x_0) < F_P(x_0) + \eta/2$, and thus $\|\Pi_{P+\epsilon I}(-(P+\epsilon I)^{-1} v) - \Pi_P(-P^{-1} v)\| \le \delta$.  Since this is true for all $\delta > 0$,
we conclude that $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \Pi_{P+\epsilon I}(-(P+\epsilon I)^{-1} v) = \Pi_P(-P^{-1} v)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure about the two last steps. I see that, due to the uniform convergence $F_{P + \epsilon I} \rightarrow F_P$, for $\left\| x-x_0\right\| > \delta$ and $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small, we have $F_{P + \epsilon I}(x) > F_P(x_0) + \eta/2$ and $F_{P + \epsilon I}(x_0) < F_P(x_0) + \eta/2$. Why these two imply that $\left\| \Pi_{P + \epsilon I}( -(P+\epsilon)^{-1} v ) - x_0\right\| \leq \delta$?

Comment: It can't be $> \delta$ because if $\|x - x_0\| > \delta$, $x_0$ has a lower value of $F_{P+\epsilon I}$ than $x$ does.